# Div element Draggable and resizable on fix places using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I've tried many draggable and resizable element using jquery like:

```
http://interactjs.io/
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
etc
```

But does not achievable as my requirement.

I want like min 50% (draggable to left or right and top or bottom) and 100% (draggable top and bottom)

It should drag on fix area not like anywhere in page like interactjs demo.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, if you can show us your code until now, the code you used to try to achieve your desired result. Is hard to know the correct solution if you don't provide us the [mcve]

Comment: Calvin, we implemented this. interactjs